# Python Can't Send Emails with URL to Gmail

Tags: python, email, gmail

I have a python script that sends email every time something is out of stock on a website. The email goes through fine if it doesnt contain URL but if it does I get a rejection email:

Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 Rejected by outbound spam filtering E005 (5df79c8f-fc91-11ed-9bc8-00163c87da3f)

This is the code I'm using:

```py
    def send_email(name):
        with open('file/config.json') as file:
            config = json.load(file)

        username = config['username']
        password = config['password']

        fromAddress = config['fromAddress']
        toAddress = config['toAddress']

        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "Out Of Stock Report "+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        msg['From'] = fromAddress
        msg['To'] = toAddress
        html = MIMEText(name, 'html')
        msg.attach(html)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('company.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)

        print(html)

        server.send_message(msg)
        server.quit()
```

If I dont include any URL in the item field the email is recieved fine through gmail